# Change Category Page in Magento2

Tags: magento-2.0.7

By Default if we see at category page (listing page) it's show product collection of category but I want to change it.

What I want to do is below.

For ex: I have category **test** and it has subcategory **demo1** , **demo2** , **demo3** , **demo4** and all these **demo** subcategory have products.

SO if I open **test** category then I want to show all **demo** subcategory with it's **name** , **image** and **product count** not **test** category products.

After that when I click on any subcategory like **demo1** then it's show product collection of **demo1** category.

How can I get this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is little help but yet you will need to override template apart from this and also will need little changes in your code as per your requirement,

```
$_helper    = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output');
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$category = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_category');
$childcategories = $category->getChildrenCategories();

foreach($childcategories as $child)
{
    $cat = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')->load($child->getId()); 


     if ($_imgUrl = $cat->getImageUrl())
             {
        $_imgHtml = '<div class="category-image"><img src="' . $_imgUrl . '" alt="' . $block->escapeHtml($cat->getName()) . '" title="' . $block->escapeHtml($cat->getName()) . '" class="image" /></div>';
        $_imgHtml = $_helper->categoryAttribute($cat, $_imgHtml, 'image');
        /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_imgHtml;
}
    echo $cat->getName();
```

I have added above code in 
**vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/category/products.phtml** for testing purpose. Strongly do not recommend to change core files that was just testing purpose.
You will need to override file and then needs to check if category is parent/top level only then above code gets executed else not.

Also currently I have not added product count but with little code you can explore that too.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks @RJ07 your code is working perfect. now if category don't have sub-category then I want to show category product. How can I do that?

Comment: Glad to know :) In above code you can get count($childcategories) , if you get count > 0 let the rest of the custom code execute else you can continue default code.

Comment: How can I get sub-category url?

Comment: And can you explain me 
**$_helper    = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output');
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$category = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_category');**

because so many times I see above code but not understand.

Comment: you can get category url once category object is loaded. So as we have cat object in $cat you can fetch url after that as , $cat->getUrl();

Comment: $helper object is in code to call helper function of categoryAttribute for the purpose to display image that I have used in code. 
And object manager creates instance of class and then you can retrieve current category using that instance from registry. So As I did.

You can also refer this link http://alanstorm.com/magento_2_object_manager for concept purpose.

Comment: Good To know worked for you. If you found something useful you can upvote and accept answer ;)

Comment: if I want to get product count of **$child** in above code how can I get that?

Comment: Yes as I have mentioned "Also currently I have not added product count but with little code you can explore that too. " I have not yet explored how to do that but surely you can get that.

Comment: I have post one more question if you can help me. please check
http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/124411/how-to-change-layout-for-desktop-and-mobile-in-magento2